# How can I use parameterized PHP PDO to drop a MySQL event?

Tags: php, mysql

```
    public function dMySQLEvent($my_env, $my_event_name) {

        $my_success = 0;
        $my_message = '';

        try {

            # declare & set variables using $my_env
            list ($db_dbdriver, $db_hostname, $db_database, $db_username, $db_password) = Connection::dbConnect($my_env);

            # set default timezone

            # create & set connection

            # WORKS
                # $conn->exec("DROP EVENT IF EXISTS " . $my_event_name . ";");

            # DOES NOT WORK
                # Prepare an SQL statement
                $my_sql = "DROP EVENT IF EXISTS :My_Event_Name";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($my_sql);

            # bind parameters to prevent SQL Injection
            $stmt->bindValue(':My_Event_Name', $my_event_name);

            # execute the SQL statement
            $stmt->execute();

            # closes the cursor, enabling the statement to be executed again
            $stmt->closeCursor();

            # close & unset the connection
            $stmt = null;
            unset($stmt);
            $conn = null;
            unset($conn);

            # Set success value to TRUE
            $my_success = 1;
            $my_message = 'success';

        } catch(PDOException $e) {

            # Append error message to error log

        }

        return array($my_success, $my_message);

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can only pass *values* to a prepared statement. That's the whole point. If you could alter the query itself, we'd be back at SQL injections.

So, no, you cannot use statement parameters for SQL identifiers. If you have a fixed set of possible events, use a whitelist. Otherwise you'll have to manually escape and filter the input (this is risky and not recommended).